# API not syncing files to Icinga2 satellite

Tags: icinga2, icingaweb2

I have a master and a satellite going over the internet. I cannot get the files from the master to sync to the satellite. I am looking under /var/lib/icinga2/api. There is no zones file.

My master zones file is as follows -

```
object Zone "master" {
    endpoints = [ "master1" ]
}
object Endpoint "master1" {
    host = "192.168.1.69"
    port = "5665"
}
object Zone "Zone-Test" {
    endpoints = [ "test-satellite-a" ]
}
object Endpoint "test-satellite-a" {
    host = "51.52.53.54"
    port = "5665"
}
object Zone "global-templates" {
    global = true
}
```

The zones on the satellite are as follows -

```
object Endpoint "master1" {
    host = "41.42.43.44"
    port = "5665"
}
object Zone "master" {
    endpoints = [ "master1" ]
}
object Endpoint NodeName {
}
object Zone ZoneName {
    endpoints = [ NodeName ]
    parent = "master"
}
object Zone "global-templates" {
    global = true
}
```

When I run service icinga2 status, I get the following -

> Nov 24 19:35:17 master1 icinga2[21599]: [2017-11-24 19:34:17 +0000] information/WorkQueue: #7 (IdoMysqlConnection, ido-mysql) items: 2, rate: 5.35/s (321/min 808/5min 808/15min);
>   Nov 24 19:35:17 master1 icinga2[21599]: [2017-11-24 19:34:17 +0000] information/ApiListener: New client connection for identity 'test-satellite-a' from [51.52.53.54]:37376
>   Nov 24 19:35:17 master1 icinga2[21599]: [2017-11-24 19:34:17 +0000] warning/ApiListener: No data received on new API connection for identity 'test-satellite-a'. Ensure that the remote endpoints are properly configured in a cluster setup.
>   Nov 24 19:35:17 master1 icinga2[21599]: Context:
>   Nov 24 19:35:17 master1 icinga2[21599]: (0) Handling new API client connection
>   Nov 24 19:35:17 master1 icinga2[21599]: [2017-11-24 19:34:27 +0000] information/WorkQueue: #7 (IdoMysqlConnection, ido-mysql) items: 8, rate: 5.5/s (330/min 835/5min 835/15min);
>   Nov 24 19:35:17 master1 icinga2[21599]: [2017-11-24 19:34:37 +0000] information/WorkQueue: #7 (IdoMysqlConnection, ido-mysql) items: 2, rate: 5.5/s (330/min 890/5min 890/15min);
>   Nov 24 19:35:17 master1 icinga2[21599]: [2017-11-24 19:34:47 +0000] information/WorkQueue: #7 (IdoMysqlConnection, ido-mysql) items: 2, rate: 5.33333/s (320/min 1025/5min 1025/15min);
>   Nov 24 19:35:17 master1 icinga2[21599]: [2017-11-24 19:35:07 +0000] information/WorkQueue: #7 (IdoMysqlConnection, ido-mysql) items: 6, rate: 5.5/s (330/min 1091/5min 1091/15min);
>   Nov 24 19:35:17 master1 icinga2[21599]: [2017-11-24 19:35:17 +0000] information/WorkQueue: #7 (IdoMysqlConnection, ido-mysql) items: 8, rate: 5.46667/s (328/min 1134/5min 1134/15min);

Any ideas what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to add the following to the zones.conf:

```
object Zone "director-global" {
  global = true
}
```

This defines a global zone for the Icinga Director.
 This is required to sync configuration commands,
 templates, apply rules, etc. to satellite and clients.
 All nodes require the same configuration and must
 have `accept_config` enabled in the `api` feature.

Answer (score 0):

The host port setting need to be configured either in the master or in the satellite..

Since its over the Internet make sure there is no reachability issue.

Also I assume you have added some config for the satellite zone. Only configs for the global zone and satellite zone get synced to the satellite.